# How to setup dockerized convoy-nfs in rancher using Chef

Tags: docker, chef-infra, nfs, rancher

I am trying to do implement dockerized convoy-nfs in chef and I cannot seem to get it right. I am using docker cookbook/resources for this. The "convoy-nfs-storagepool" exits with the message "waiting for metadata ...unable to find the metadata" .

The docker-compose and rancher-compose code is in git and that is my reference.
[GIT](https://gist.github.com/arkka/b0b1f2a091d3f5e24229f40f72a5a19b) . There is a "metadata" field in the rancher-compose.yml and I am not sure how to use that in chef.

I am new to docker and this is my chef-recipe so far:

```
docker_image 'rancher/convoy-agent' do
  tag 'v0.9.0'
  action :pull
end

docker_container 'convoy-nfs-storagepool' do
  labels ['io.rancher.container.create_agent:true', 'io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label:nfs-server=true']
  labels ['mount_dir:/', "nfs_server:#{node['hostname']}"]$
  command "storagepool-agent"
  repo 'rancher/convoy-agent:v0.9.0'
  volumes [ '/var/run:/host/var/run', '/run:/host/run']
  subscribes :run, 'docker_image[rancher/convoy-agent]'
end

docker_container 'convoy-nfs' do
  labels ['io.rancher.scheduler.global:true', 'io.rancher.container.create_agent:true']
  labels ['mount_dir:/', "nfs_server:#{node['hostname']}", 'mount_opts: proto=tcp,port=2049,nfsvers=4']$
  command "volume-agent-nfs"
  repo 'rancher/convoy-agent:v0.9.0'
  pid_mode host
  privileged true
  volumes [ '/var/run:/host/var/run', '/run:/host/run', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro', '/proc:/host/proc', '/etc/docker/plugins:/etc/docker/plugins']
  subscribes :run, 'docker_image[rancher/convoy-agent]'
end

docker _image 'cpuguy83/nfs-server' do
  action :pull
end

docker_container 'nfs' do
  repo 'cpuguy83/nfs-server'
  command "/exports"
  privileged true
  volumes "/exports"
  subscribes :run, 'docker_image[cpuguy83/nfs-server]'
end
```